# php script for magento

Tags: php, magento, categories

I have a magento shop with over 3000 products and 1000 categories.

```
Category I
      Category 1
      Category 2
Category II
      Category 3
      Category 4
```

My problem is that all the products are only in the deepest categories. For example: A product in Category 3 also has to be in Category II, but it's not. Is there a way to do this via php script with all the products?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Properly is, although it would take some planning to make sure it moves the right products around :)

Comment: Can you post some of your actual structure, attempts on the issue, minimal verifiable examples...?

Comment: Easiest would probably be to buy some of the many existing modules, like this one:  http://www.extendware.com/magento-category-copy.html
There might even be free alternatives out there.

Comment: this is the current shop: http://www.ihnkenrollen.de/   you need to go through all the parent categories to reach the products in the deepest one

Comment: What about setting parent categories as Anchors to display products from children categories ??

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple module which will have a single data-install script with something like this inside :

```
$categoryi = array(6);
$category2 = 20;

$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category2);
/* @var $category Mage_Catalog_Model_Category */

$productsCollection = $category->getProductCollection();
/* @var $productsCollection Varien_Data_Collection_Db */

$products = $productsCollection->getItems();
/* @var $products array of Mage_Catalog_Model_Product */

foreach($products as $product) {
    /* @var $product Mage_Catalog_Model_Product */
    $categories = $product->getCategoryIds();
    $categories = array_unique(array_merge($categories, $categoryi));
    $product->setCategoryIds($categories);
    $product->save();
}
```

Basically, `$categoryi` is the category you want to assign to your products. `$category2` is the category to retrieve your products from.

This script is just an example. You will have to modify it to fit your categories ids and maybe add a loop so it works for all your categories!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to activate the option is Anchor in the categories to show the child categories products on it.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think that any coding is needed for this. You can try the following:

- Open Category 1
- Go to Display settings
- Set "Is Anchor" from "No" to "Yes"
- Save category 1
- Go to the index management
- re-index the index item "category products"

Check the frontend. The products from the subcategory should now be shown also in the parent categories. If this works change it for all the categories. Or make a script to update this category setting instead.

Good luck!